# How to get a GUI to show up like its 'floating' with the foremost active background app still active?

Tags: macos

I would like to make own GUI like spotlight (sort of like alfred), where I press a short key ,like Option + Space and a gui bar just like Alfred shows up.

I would like to code the app my self, but i am not sure how to get a gui to show up like its 'floating' with foremostactive background app still active. Just looking for any directions on where the documentation for creating such an app is.

Any links would be much appreciated!

Comment: https://github.com/albertlauncher Albert

Comment: @PepeNO can you explain how your given link is related to the question?

Comment: Here is an open source Swift library that looks like it does exactly what you want: https://github.com/dagronf/DSFQuickActionBar

Comment: I looked at albert, seems to be the UI i am hoping for. But I would like to code my own app and just the UI shell using Swift/Objective-c AppleScriptObjc Solution. Any documentation/tutorial on that or links are much appreciated :)

@MosheKatz link is a good place to start but more is appreciated :D

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find documentation on on an app as an agent and able to use DFSQuickActionBar to get the task done.
https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/technotes/tn2083/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS10003794

Thank you @MosheKatz for the answer! I would be happy to mark your answer as the right one if you can repost not as a comment!